# Batch sending an net stop output to a text file

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd

If I have the following script:

```
echo start
net stop Wsearch /yes 2 >> Log.txt
echo stop
```

When it runs I still get a on screen output why is this and how do I stop it. I have `>> Log.txt` to send it to a text file and this works with other commands just not this one can any one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to direct the error message, which is bound to result from that command, you need to remove the space after the "2" like this:

```
net stop Wsearch /yes 2>> Log.txt
```

But I wonder why you want to run a command that you know will result in an error message. The Windows Indexing Service "Wsearch" cannot be stopped like this.See [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/91ce8049-3604-4675-b9e7-7a49be5873c4/how-to-pause-or-snooze-indexing-programmatically?forum=windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment)

Comment: Thanks this was an example I have 20-30 commands like this one stopping various things. And I didn't want it to to display what it is doing just when it has done.

Comment: I have just fixed my pc so I tested it and I am still getting an on screen output.

Comment: Edit your answer and show what it looks like then please.

Comment: it looks something like this: "Windows search is stopping..." then "Windows search stopped successfully"

Comment: Try redirecting stream 1, which is the "normal" output to one file and stream 2, which is for error messages, to a different file like this: "net stop Wsearch /yes > 1.txt 2>  2.txt" Then you can look in 1.txt and 2.txt and see which stream has the output you do/don't want.

Comment: If you just want to throw away a stream, you can direct it to the special file "nul", like this "net stop ... 2> nul"

Comment: If you want to append stream 1 to a file, use double greater than symbols, like this "command >> 1.txt". And if you want to append stream 2 to a file, use "command 2>> 2.txt"

Comment: I need it to go to the same file though.

Comment: net stop Wsearch /yes >> log.txt 2>&1

Comment: That says... run net stop and append the output to log.txt, oh, and by the way, send error messages there too.

Comment: Excellent! For future reference, it is called "Output Redirection" and there is plenty of helpful info here   http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php